# Rails 'Preview State' Using Cookies/Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables, preview

This seems to be a common question, but I've yet to find a very 'detailed' answer - I'm looking for the best way to allow users to preview the form they are going to submit, before submitting it.

Obviously, storing this in the db isnt the best option (which is what I'm doing right now) because there has to be a process to remove it, and that has a lot of scenarios.

***Details***
I don't want to show the user the **edit** action, I want to show the user the **show** action, and at the top and bottom of the screen have a **Publish** button.

My questions:

1. How would you go about storing the information from the form into a session *(looking for some controller code)*
2. How would you know in the **show** action that you are displaying a preview, rather than a 'real' object. (or would you have a separate action for preview?) *(looking for some controller/view code here)*
3. How would you remove the session data once the user is 'done' with it?

I think that storing in the database has the same issue with storing it in the session, the cleanup, am I wrong? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not a real answer but some inspiration there: https://github.com/MrRuru/rails_form_autosave

Comment: I don't like idea storing data in session, because in some cases it may consume a lot of space.  I see nothing wrong in storing unpublished records in the database.  Probably, you only need to add some boolean attribute "published".  In the show view show form with button "publish" in case record is not published yet.  And rake task to clear obsolete unpublished records.

Comment: @apneadiving very nice, thank you I'll check it out.

Comment: @taro I would agree, and like I said, the db is how it is currently implemented with a 'state' field - but how do I know when it is obsolete? Do I assume after so much time its no longer in use? Have a background process go through and remove them? I would have to notify the user that preview expires in so much time and will be deleted. With the 'state' column they have the ability to save as a draft.. if it was going to expire, save it, no?

Comment: You can consider unpublished records created more than few days ago as obsolete (user should be noticed about that policy).  Rake task may be executed via cron once a day or more frequently. Also, you can implement some separate rake task to notify users about pending unpublished records, which will be removed soon.  Drafts may be untouched if you like at all or for a longer time.

Comment: I considered using a delayed job type of method, when the users click preview it fires off a delayed job to happen in say.. 5 hours. On the preview screen screen notify users that the record will be no longer available in n hours, and when the time comes, delayed job removes the record.

Comment: @taro, would you mind throwing in your most recent comment as an answer? I ended up using the db method and deleting them after they are x days old.. I'd like to close this and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider unpublished records created more than few days ago as obsolete (user must know about that policy). Rake task may be executed via cron once a day or more frequently. Also, you can implement some separate rake task to notify users about pending unpublished records, which will be removed soon. Drafts is a great idea and may be untouched if you like at all or for a longer time.